# Python: Unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, integer, typeerror

I am trying to implement a function in Python that will take a list of integers as input and return the sum of all the even numbers in the list. I have written the following code, but it is giving me an error when I try to run it.

```
def sum_evens(numbers):
    result = 0
    for num in numbers:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            result += num
    return result

print(sum_evens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'.
```

Can someone please help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can fix it?

Comment: working fine on my side..!

Comment: The code works fine. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: The error is not in your code.. assuming firstly you are taking numbers in string format that's why this error shown up but now you takin input in int format so no error..!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my computer. However, guessing by your error message, `num` must be a string. You can fix this by converting it to an integer beforehand:

```py
def sum_evens(numbers):
    result = 0
    for num in numbers:
        # convert to integer
        num = int(num)

        if num % 2 == 0:
            result += num
    return result
```

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative using the list comprehension concept (functional paradigm):

```
def sum_evens(numbers):
  return sum(int(num) for num in numbers if int(num) % 2 == 0)
```